# Finding maximum index of a specific value where it occurs consecutively more than N times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array like this

```
sample = np.array([[9.99995470e-01],
                   [9.99992013e-01],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [9.99775827e-01],
                   [9.99439061e-01],
                   [9.98361528e-01],
                   [9.96853650e-01],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [1.00000000e+00],
                   [9.99999762e-01]])
```

I want to get the max index where the values = 1 and it occurs consecutively more than 5 times. So the output should be index no 15.

I wonder if there is a simple function to solve this

Comment: I guess you need to find `[1, 1,  1, 1, 1]` instead of just `== 1` check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100242/python-numpy-first-occurrence-of-subarray)

Answer (score 2):

Using groupby

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

def find_max_index(arr):

  # consecutive runs of ones
  # Use enumerate so we have the index with each value
  run_ones = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(enumerate(sample.flatten()), lambda x: x[1]) if k == 1]

  # Sorting by length to insure that max is at end of the list of lists
  # Since this is a stable last item will still be the largest index
  run_ones.sort(key=len) 

  last_list = run_ones[-1]
  if len(last_list) > 5:        # need max to have at least a run of five
    return last_list[-1][0]     # index of last value in max run of ones
  else:
    return None

print(find_max_index(sample))

# Output: 15
```

**Explanation**

function *find_max_index*

1. groupby keeps groups runs of ones in sublist.  Each item is index, value pair (from enumerate)

   run_ones = [[(2, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 1.0), (5, 1.0)], [(10, 1.0), (11, 1.0), (12, 1.0), (13, 1.0), (14, 1.0), (15, 1.0)]]
2. Sort list to insure max is at end

   run_ones: [[(2, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 1.0), (5, 1.0)], [(10, 1.0), (11, 1.0), (12, 1.0), (13, 1.0), (14, 1.0), (15, 1.0)]]
3. Last list containing run of ones

   last_list: [(10, 1.0), (11, 1.0), (12, 1.0), (13, 1.0), (14, 1.0), (15, 1.0)]
4. Index of the last tuple in last_list

   last_list[-1][0]

Comment: It should be not just the biggest index of one but the highest index of the longest window of ones.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the index of the last appearance of 1 in a group of 5.

Input:

```
max([index for index, window in enumerate(windowed(sample, 5)) if list(window) == [1]*5]) + 4
```

Output:

```
15
```

Comment: What is `windowed`? Do you import it from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will solve your problems for you

```
def find_repeated_index(sample, min_value, min_repeats):
  max_index = -1
  history   = []
  for index, value in enumerate(np.array(sample).flatten()):
    if value >= min_value: 
        history.append(value)
        if len(history) >= min_repeats: max_index = index
    else:
        if len(history) >= min_repeats: break                  
        history = []
  return max_index

find_repeated_index(sample, 1.0, 5)
15

find_repeated_index(sample, 1.0, 4)
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can solve this with O(n) runtime complexity and without allocating extra memory (not counting flattening and to list transformation).

```
def find_last_index_of_longest_window(array, window_value):

    if len(array) <= 0:
        return -1

    if len(array) == 1:
        return 0 if array[0] == window_value else -1

    max_length = 0
    length = 0

    for i, value in enumerate(array):
        if value == window_value:
            length += 1
        else:
            if length >= max_length:
                max_length = length
                max_index = i - 1
                length = 0

    if length > max_length:
        max_length = length
        max_index = i

    return max_index


print(find_last_index_of_longest_window(sample.flatten().tolist(), 1.0))
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to avoid flattening and conversion to list:

```
def find_last_index_of_longest_window(array, window_value):

    if len(array) <= 0:
        return -1

    if len(array) == 1:
        return 0 if array[0][0] == window_value else -1

    max_length = 0
    length = 0

    for i, item in enumerate(array):
        value = item[0]
        if value == window_value:
            length += 1
        else:
            if length >= max_length:
                max_length = length
                max_index = i - 1
                length = 0

    if length > max_length:
        max_length = length
        max_index = i

    return max_index


print(find_last_index_of_longest_window(sample, 1.0))
```

Comment: this one works too, but how do I determine which one is the most efficient way?

Comment: In this case, just pass the numpy array to the function and adjust the function to take the first element of the array item (because it's array of one-item arrays) but in this case the function won't be generic and will depend on numpy array layout.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/alimanfoo/c5977e87111abe8127453b21204c1065):

```
def find_runs(x):
    """Find runs of consecutive items in an array."""

    # ensure array
    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    if x.ndim != 1:
        raise ValueError('only 1D array supported')
    n = x.shape[0]

    # handle empty array
    if n == 0:
        return np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])

    else:
        # find run starts
        loc_run_start = np.empty(n, dtype=bool)
        loc_run_start[0] = True
        np.not_equal(x[:-1], x[1:], out=loc_run_start[1:])
        run_starts = np.nonzero(loc_run_start)[0]

        # find run values
        run_values = x[loc_run_start]

        # find run lengths
        run_lengths = np.diff(np.append(run_starts, n))

        return run_values, run_starts, run_lengths

# Part added by me

values,indices,lengths = find_runs(sample.flatten())
ones = np.where(values==1)
fiveormore = np.where(lengths[ones]>=5)
r = indices[ones][fiveormore]
last_indices = r + lengths[ones][fiveormore] - 1
```

The `last_indices` variable will be an array of the last indices of each 5 or longer consecutive part of the array where the value is 1. Getting the last of these indices is just a `last_indices[-1]` call. If there are no such indices the array will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Quick profiling for large arrays shows that the following solution based on the code from [*Counting consecutive 1's in NumPy array*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42129021/7851470) will be significantly faster than the other ones presented here:

```
import numpy as np


def group_cumsum(a):
    """Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42129610"""
    a_ext = np.concatenate(([0], a, [0]))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a_ext[1:] != a_ext[:-1])
    a_ext[1:][idx[1::2]] = idx[::2] - idx[1::2]
    return a_ext.cumsum()[1:-1]


array = sample[:, 0]
value = 1
n = 5

mask = array == value
cumsums = group_cumsum(mask)
if not np.any(cumsums > n):
    print(f"No more than {n} consecutive {value}'s are found in the array.")
else:
    index = len(sample) - np.argmax(cumsums[::-1] > n) - 1
    print(index)  # returns 15 for your example
```